# Macro for excel VBA will not run second sub in same module

Tags: excel, indexing, hyperlink, autofill, vba

Below is a macro i am currently using for some invoice tabs. the first sheet in the workbook is set up for indexing using worksheet names for the hyperlinks. this module was set up to be activated by crtl+shift+n. the second sub worked the first couple of times i tried it but now it is not copying data from the previous row filled to the first empty row filled. it seems like it stops after the first sub. Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewRequistionRecord()
'
' NewRequistionRecord Macro
' Used for creaing a new requistion record to be auto updated in master 
Requisitions worksheet
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+N
'

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.sheets("BlankReq")
Dim wbBefore As Workbook: Set wbBefore = Application.Workbooks("OPP Stores 
Orders Macro.xlsm")
Dim wsBefore As Worksheet: Set wsBefore = wbBefore.sheets("BlankReq")
Dim answer
Dim NewName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ws.Select 'Goes to template worksheet


    ws.Copy Before:=wsBefore ' Forces a copy to be made always before the template so it is always at the end    
sheets("BlankReq (2)").Select
sheets("BlankReq (2)").Name = "Enter Req Number" ' changes the name to indicate a requisition number needs to be entered
Range("A1").Select ' hyperlink goes back  Master Req index page
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

sheets("Enter Req Number").Select
answer = MsgBox("Please rename the sheet with the Requisition number", vbOK)

    If answer = vbOK Then

Another:
    NewName = InputBox("Requisition number - ?")
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewName

    Range("D2").Select
    NewName = InputBox("Requisition Description- NO SPACES!! USE UNDERSCORE ?")
    Range("D2").Value = NewName
    wsBefore.Select

    Range("H2").Select
    NewName = InputBox("Please enter Requested By ")
    Range("H2").Value = NewName
    wsBefore.Select
    answer = MsgBox("Please select your data to copy and paste into this sheet. Line Cost must be selected seperately from the items.", vbOKOnly)

    End If

End Sub


Sub Filldown()
Dim strFormulas(1 To 6) As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim wbBefore As Workbook: Set wbBefore = Application.Workbooks("OPP StoresOrders Macro.xlsm")
Dim wsBefore As Worksheet: Set wsBefore = wbBefore.sheets("BlankReq")
Dim LRow As Long
Dim xRow As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With ThisWorkbook.sheets("Requisitions")
        Range("A1").Select
        Columns("B:K").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        End With




Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut is probably set to a Sub, not to a Module. Thus, the second sub is probably not running by default.

To run the first sub first and then the second sub, try the following:

```
Sub TestMe()
    NewRequistionRecord
    FillDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the second macro at all. So it runs through the code, and at no point does it get the message to run the second macro. You need to tell your program somehow to run the second macro - I like
 `call Macroname`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: Hey, we all start somewhere! Think of Modules like spreadsheets - you have them, they store code. Each sub within the module is a separate macro. You can create a shortcut/button to each individual macro. If you want to use multiple macros at once, you need a "wrapper" macro to hold them all - like Sub Wrapper() Call Macro1 Call Macro2 End sub

Comment: Just to mention that the `Call` statement is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Instead just write `Macroname` (without call).

Comment: Call is still needed when you have multi-input functions. I'm also a fan of it since it explicitly shows and reminds "Hey, this is grabbing another macro, remember?" Now you were mentioning it shouldn't be used - Is there a reason to avoid using it?