# Sub calls First Sub but does not call second sub

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I am trying to have a sub run a series of other subs but am not having much luck. The Sub looks like this:

```
Private Sub OKCommand_Click()

new_tab
metric_transfer

End Sub
```

When I comment out the first sub, the second sub runs. I put in Debug.Print comments above and below the second sub and watched it run right over the sub without calling it. I tried putting `Call` and `Application.Run` in front but the former did nothing and the latter was the wrong approach. My example follows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908468/macro-for-excel-vba-will-not-run-second-sub-in-same-module) but it is unclear if the matter was ever resolved in that case. I didn't try [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/773914-vba-main-only-runs-first-sub.html) delay technique as it didn't appear to work for them either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Put a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/set-and-clear-a-breakpoint) on the `metric_transfer` line. When it is hit, keep pressing F8.

Comment: `Call` is useless. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. If the code doesn't compile anymore, there's a typo somewhere. Where are the procedures located? Can you [edit] your post to include them?

Comment: For how you describe it, it seems like the code in the procedure `new_tab` does something that invalidates what the sub `metric_transfer` is supposed to do. You should probably debug step by step the code in `new_tab` and see what happens that make your code crash/exiting. Also, by the name of the sub `new_tab`, something tells me you're adding a new sheet to your workbook... is it maybe that `metric_transfer`'s code doesn't work when the focus is on this new sheet? Please share the code inside `new_tab` to give us more clue.

Comment: post the code for new_tab and metric_transfer

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GSerg. I was using `Debug.Print` for this but this approach is far more succinct.

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu. Option Explicit is at the top of the userform and I have enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo. I had debugged it but it wasn't crashing so much as ignoring the second sub. `new_tab` was indeed doing something to invalidate the sub `metric_transfer`. Apparently, having `Unload Me` in `new_tab` caused it to skip the sub. I'm not clear why but will post an answer as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: Sounds good, but we can't see your code and there's not enough of it in the post for anyone to do anything more than try to guess what's going on. Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: _"Apparently, having `Unload Me` in `new_tab` caused it to skip the sub"_. Well, of course! If you read the documentation, you can see that _When an object is unloaded, it's removed from memory and all memory associated with the object is reclaimed_. Your macro `OKCommand_Click` is part of the userform, so if you `Unload` the user form, the memory is released and the execution of `OKCommand_Click` is stopped (that's why you never execute the second one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Matteo for pointing me in the right direction. The problem that I encountered was the result of an `Unload Me` line in the `new_tab` sub. All of these procedures were on the user form. When `Unload Me` executed, it wiped the userform from memory as described [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-between-form1hide-and-unload-me-3424279). It appears that hiding the form would have been the better option with `form1.Hide`. Not only because of the issues this caused here but also because I would need information from this form at a later point.